# How do I remove a rootkit without an anti-rootkit program?

Tags: malware, windows-2000, rootkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

Windows 2000 Server.

I believe I have a rootkit.  But, nothing will remove it.  I've tried everything.  Even tools that are merely for scanning fail or bsod the computer.

Since nothing works, I wanted to try and do it manually.

edit:  This is a Windows 2000 Server Forest Root.  I cannot rebuild it without blowing up the domain.

Comment: Can you really be certain about the integrity of your server after such a compromise? It may be wiser to rebuild.

Comment: You reinstall from scratch or from a known clean image.

Comment: I can't rebuild.  It's my forest root server.  Reinstall is not an option.  I have tried every rootkit tool and or scanner out there.  Things that do show processes, etc. do not yield anything useful.  I've done all the things you an imagine.

Comment: You will never be able to trust this system again - reinstall and recover from know good backups is the only real solution.

Comment: @johny Not only *can* you rebuild a Forest Root Server, you should have a contingency plan (DRP, BCP) sitting around with directions of how to do so.

Comment: If you "can't rebuild" then what would you do if your server died? You have a contingency for that right? You know you can create a new DC in that domain and transfer all the roles as part of removing the suspect one, right?

Answer (score 7):

I'd strongly advise to rebuild your server.

- if the server has been root-compromised how can you assure integrity
  of all of its parts even if you THINK you've removed the compromised
  part ?
- it's easier and saves the time and hassle - rebuild and restore from
  backups

Comment: I cannot rebuild.  It is a forest root.

Comment: @johnny set up a new server, dcpromo it and transfer the FSMOs. Also, make sure to use a *supported* version of Windows Server - Windows 2000 had its end of support 2 years ago.